# How to express that something was very difficult: with great/a lot/much difficulty?

Tags: sentence-choice

I found these sentences in a book, which one is correct:

1.He escaped death with great difficulty.

2.He escaped death with a lot of difficulty

3.He escaped death with much difficulty.

If all these sentences are correct which one is better? Can we write a sentence that is better than these three sentences without changing the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All you example sentences are correct and have the same meaning.
>   He escaped death with **great** difficulty

shows that more effort was necessary the the other two sentences.

> He escaped death **overcoming** great difficulty
>   he escaped death **overcoming insurmountable odds**

would be other ways to describe the achievement with more focus on what needed to be done.